# How to compare start time and end time when the time format is customized one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frame-rate, timecodes

I have my time format as  00:00:00:00  (HH : MM : SS: FF) where FF denotes framerate -29fps. Can anybody help how to validate the start time and end time using jQuery, when end time should not be less than start time.

Comment: compare their hours, then minutes, then seconds. as soon as one is bigger, that's the bigger time. (I'm assuming framerate doesn't matter)

Comment: Thanks Stephen...seems it makes sense.. let me try it! :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Use this library [moment](https://momentjs.com/).
Use the `moment.diff()` function to get the difference.
Go through the docs for reference.